# Can I modify the core library's comment macro to censor out swearing?

Tags: clojure, macros, comments

The comment macro is delightfully simple.

```
(defmacro comment
  "Ignores body, yields nil"
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& body])
```

Can this be modified to censor out words? For example, can I replace my colleague's constant use of "f***" in the `comment` macro just by editing the `comment` macro itself? Or will the `comment` macro's inherent non-evaluation of its body stop my little prank?

Example: I want to change `(comment I f***ing hate this code)` to `(comment I ducking hate this code)`.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. What is a specific use case you hope will work? Like what is an input and the output/behavior you want?

Comment: @amalloy Fair point. Making edit.

Comment: The edit doesn't really make any sense still. The `comment` form is obviously not going to rewrite the source code saved to disk; it just changes how it's evaluated. The input you provide normally does nothing, of course, when evaluated; what do you hope will happen when the output is evaluated? To me it looks like it will still do nothing, because it is surrounded by a `comment`.

Comment: @amalloy That's why I've asked. I don't expect it to work either, but I'm trying my luck.

Comment: Suggested reading: [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `comment` already censors everything - the result of its evaluation is `nil`.

Looks like you want to rewrite the source code instead of changing how clojure treats the body of the `comment`. Sometimes teams run code formatter as a pre-commit hook. It should not be hard to replace all occurences of `f***` with `duck` with a sed command and set it as a pre-commit hook.

Alternative approach is to setup git filter that on checkout replaces `duck` with `f***` and on commit converts back. This way repository will be censored but local representation can be with profanity. https://www.agwa.name/projects/git-crypt/ uses this approach to keep local files decrypted but encrypted on remote.